# WebTarget from String

Tags: java, rest, url, jersey-client

I'm consuming a REST API via Jersey-Client. The API is paginated.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient()
        .register(HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(USER_NAME, PASSWORD));

WebTarget target = client.target(HOST).path(API_BASE).path("content");
PageResult pageResult = target.request(JSON).get()readEntity(PageResult.class);
```

The response looks something like this:

```
{
    "results":[...
    ],
    "start": 0,
    "limit": 25,
    "size": 25,
    "_links": {
        "self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content",
        "next": "/rest/api/content?limit=25&start=25",
        "base": "http://localhost:8090",
        "context": ""
    }
}
```

The `pageResult` object is populated correctly with the response.
Now I want to create a new `WebTarget` or reuse the current `WebTarget`. What has changed are the query parameters.

What is the easiest way to create the new `WebTarget`?

```
target = client.target(pageResult._links.base).path(pageResult._links.next);
```

This way the query parameters are not interpreted correctly. I also don't want to parse the url by myself. What API is there? I could add the query parameters by hand, but I think there should be a method like `WebTarget.fromString(pageResult._links.base + pageResult._links.next)`

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
target = client.target(pageResult._links.base).path(pageResult._links.next);
```

to

```
target = client.target(pageResult._links.base + pageResult._links.next)
```

From the doku

```
/**
 * Build a new web resource target.
 *
 * @param uri web resource URI. May contain template parameters. Must not be {@code null}.
 * @return web resource target bound to the provided URI.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the supplied string is not a valid URI template.
 * @throws NullPointerException     in case the supplied argument is {@code null}.
 */
public WebTarget target(String uri);
```